# Bypassing ValueError in a for loop in python

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch, except, finally

```
def decade_total_count(decade, name):
    """
    sums up the number of births of the given 
    female baby `name` in a 10-year period
    
    Parameters:
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    decade ... starting year of the decade
    name   ... female name 
           ... str
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    """
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(decade, decade+10):
        yearly = females[(females['name']==name) & (females['year']==i)]['births'].item()
        count = count + yearly
        
    return count
```

I'm trying to use the function above to get the number of births for any name in the data but my loop stops whenever there's a year that the name does not occur in. In that case, I get this value error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/yf/s14dt13x11n82t5kg4260v800000gn/T/ipykernel_4325/1603862037.py in <module>
----> 1 total_count('Jennifer')

/var/folders/yf/s14dt13x11n82t5kg4260v800000gn/T/ipykernel_4325/1143784105.py in total_count(name)
     42 
     43     for i in range(start, end, 10):
---> 44         counts.append(decade_total_count(i, name))
     45 
     46     return counts

/var/folders/yf/s14dt13x11n82t5kg4260v800000gn/T/ipykernel_4325/1143784105.py in decade_total_count(decade, name)
     15 
     16     for i in range(decade, decade+10):
---> 17         yearly = females[(females['name']==name) & (females['year']==i)]['births'].item()
     18         count = count + yearly
     19 

~/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in item(self)
    329         if len(self) == 1:
    330             return next(iter(self))
--> 331         raise ValueError("can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar")
    332 
    333     @property

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

How can I bypass the error and keep my loop going even for years that does not contain the given 'name' in my data? I've messed around with `try`, `except`, `else`, and `finally` clause but somehow it breaks my loop and just returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I don't have enough information about the variable `female`.

Try this:

```
def decade_total_count(decade, name):
    """
    sums up the number of births of the given 
    female baby `name` in a 10-year period
    
    Parameters:
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    decade ... starting year of the decade
    name   ... female name 
           ... str
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    """
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(decade, decade+10):
        try:
            yearly = females[(females['name']==name) & (females['year']==i)]['births'].item()
        except ValueError:
            continue
        count = count + yearly
        
    return count
```

If a `ValueError` is raised, just catch it and run next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what you've tried, so I don't know where you're going wrong exactly. However, putting a try-except block within the loop should do the trick:

```
def decade_total_count(decade, name):
    """
    sums up the number of births of the given 
    female baby `name` in a 10-year period
    
    Parameters:
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    decade ... starting year of the decade
    name   ... female name 
           ... str
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    """
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(decade, decade+10):
        try:
            yearly = females[(females['name']==name) & (females['year']==i)]['births'].item()
            count = count + yearly
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Encountered error: {e}. Skipping.")
        
    return count
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this style is known as [Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission (EAFP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).